# ¿Como Insertar datos de un script de Python en mysql?

Tags: mysql, python, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Hace tiempo que no programo en python y me siento bastante oxidado con el lenguaje y por eso necesito un poco de ayuda con mi script:
https://pastebin.com/WzLYBWaU
Lo que realiza es que una vez ejecutado , todos los archivos nuevos que lleguen a una carpeta (en este caso de descarga) sean movidos a una carpeta recien creada por el script dependiendo de la fecha y hora (en este caso los archivos que lleguen cada 1 segundo se movera a la carpeta con el nombre : 25-11-2017-00-20-11. Esto se puede modificar tambien a archivos que lleguen a cada minuto, hora, dia, mes y por ultimo por año en la linea 33)
Para conectar a la base de datos las lineas son:

```
import MySQLdb


class Database:

    host = 'localhost'
    user = 'root'
    password = ''
    db = 'watcherservice'

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = MySQLdb.connect(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def insert(self, query):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
            self.connection.commit()
        except:
            self.connection.rollback()



    def query(self, query):
        cursor = self.connection.cursor( MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor )
        cursor.execute(query)

        return cursor.fetchall()

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    db = Database()
```

Los datos de mi tabla son los siguientes

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `detalles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `hora` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `archivos_movidos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `estado` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Mi dudas son:
Como inserto el numero de archivos a una carpeta que fueron movidos en la columna archivos movidos?
Si se movieron los archivos con exito o si hubo un error. Como inserto en la columna  estado 'exitoso' o 'error' ?

Comment: Hola, preguntas como ingresar datos a tu base via SQL? , y otra cosa por que no usas algún ORM para manejar tu base de datos, esto es python dónde todo es más rápido y fácil.

Comment: Se como insertar la fecha y  hora actual por medio de try:
   x.execute
   conn.commit()
except:
   conn.rollback()

conn.close(). Pero no se que poner para poder insertar la cantidad de archivos que se movieron

Comment: Por eso, necesitas guardar estos datos en tu DB, eso se hace ejecutando SQL con el cursor que tienes en tu clase.

Comment: Creo que el problema que tienes no es tanto cómo insertar en una base de datos sino más bien de implementar un algoritmo correcto que haga lo que deseas. Una posible solución sería empezar a copiar archivos a la hora X, en ese momento por cada copia con éxito realizada aumentas un contador en una variable de éxitos y en otra los fallos, una vez finalices el copiado de todos los archivos del directorio, haces el insert en la base de datos. (Para evitar abrir una conexión a la base de datos por archivo), aunque también puedes insertar un registro en la base de datos por cada archivo. Saludos.